# Help addressing recording problems in Cubase

Tags: cubase

I have Cubase LE AI 9 that came bundled with a Steinberg UR44 DAW. I'm running it on Windows 7 professional.  I'm storing files on an external hard drive.  I'm trying to record 4 tracks concurrently live -- two vocals, percussion and guitar all plugged directly into the DAW.  I am having problems with the input popping in and out in the recording.  The equipment all sounds fine through a PA and amp -- I don't think it is the analog devices or the DAW itself.  I sense that the problem is about my computer and maybe hard drive not being able to handle the data.  I'm a complete novice at recording.  It is quite possible that there might be a bit rate setting or something that would solve this problem.  But I'm pretty clueless.   Ideas?

Comment: I think you mean "sound card" instead of DAW everywhere in your question. If you are recording directly to the external HDD, it is very likely that it won't be fast enough. Why don't you record to an internal drive and *then* transfer the data later when timing is not an issue?

Answer (score 1):

OK.  For a start, the  Cubase LE AI 9 program (and the computer that runs it) is the DAW, the Steinberg UR44 is the audio interface (or, colloquially, 'sound card').

Even an external drive ought to be capable of recording four tracks.   It's not a lot of data by today's standards.  Many years ago, when my state-of-the-art PC had a Pentium 4 at 800MHz and PATA drives I ran a test and managed to play about 80 stereo audio tracks before getting bored, thinking 'that's plenty!' and giving up.

But sure, try re-assigning the Project to a folder on the internal drive of your computer and let us know if it helps.  You can always move completed Projects to an external drive for storage. (Make sure you DO create a new folder for each Project right from the outset, else chaos will ensue when you try to move it.)

Comment: Pentium IV at 800MHz?! Are you sure that was not even a Pentium III ;)?

Answer (score 0):

Also John as an addendum to those good suggestions, this guide to optimising Win 7 on the Focusrite site may be of help.

https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207359245-Optimising-your-PC-for-audio-on-Windows-7

The advise will apply to your UR44. BTW the '44 is excellent and I used one for many years. It's rock solid. :)